# Is it possible to create Laravel Blade tags that can access Controller actions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to create a Blade tag which can output data like Posts.
At the moment I'm using a PageController which returns the `show.blade.php` view.
In this view are some self created Elements (Text, Images, ...) and now I have a Bloglist Element. For the reason that I'm already using a Controller and Route, I want to create a Blade Directive which can handle this.

For example:

```
@BlogList('$filter')
  //foreach with $posts 
@endBlogList
```

Between this tags should be a `$posts` variable available, which is returned by the BlogController. The `$filter` is also for the BlogController to filter the Posts.

Comment: This kinda goes against the MVC logic for Laravel. Views are returned by Controllers, so having a `.blade` directive that accesses a Controller function seems redundant/backwards; the Controller that is returning the view can call another Controller function and pass the result to the view, like `$blogList = app()->make('AnotherController')->generateList();`, then `return view('blog-list)->with('blogList', $blogList);`. Rethink what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

<li>{{$post->title}}</li>

@endforeach
```

this assumes your controller is sending $posts to your view.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the problem is, that for this View/Route is the PageController responsible not the BlogController. I want to access the BlogController with the `@BlogList('$filter')` Blade directive.

Comment: sorry, I missunderstood your question. I don't think views can access controllers, they can only use what the controllers pass down to them (not sure though, I'm also learning laravel). You can access controllers from views, but you'd have to use an ajax call for that.

This link is the first one I found when looking for "laravel 6 ajax call", you'll find plenty of information on how to implement it:

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-ajax-request-exampleexample.html

Another option is to retrieve $posts within PageController and pass it to the view...